# How to plot dataframe rows on different colors depending on whether they are weekends

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
      values  weekend   num_festive     kind    day_name
date                    
2018-01-01  236     0.0     1.0     1.0     Monday
2018-01-02  258     0.0     0.0     0.0     Tuesday
2018-01-03  235     0.0     0.0     0.0     Wednesday
2018-01-04  219     0.0     0.0     0.0     Thursday
2018-01-05  197     0.0     0.0     0.0     Friday
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2019-12-27  234     0.0     0.0     0.0     Friday
2019-12-28  260     1.0     0.0     0.0     Saturday
2019-12-29  226     1.0     0.0     0.0     Sunday
2019-12-30  216     0.0     0.0     0.0     Monday
2019-12-31  189     0.0     0.0     0.0     Tuesday
```

and I want to plot the timeseries on different colors depending if the day is a weekend or not, having a line with different colors as this one:

[image]

I also want to be able to plot it along side another dataframe (which has the exact same format) to compare both time series. I came up with the following code, which plots nothing on to the axes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, squeeze=True)
ax18, ax19 = ax[0], ax[1]

colors = {"weekend": "powderblue", "md": "black", "gu": "orange"}
for idx, val in md18.iterrows():
    if val["weekend"]:
        ax18.plot(idx, val["value"], color=colors["weekend"]
        )
    else:
        ax18.plot(idx, val["value"], color=colors["md"])

colors = {"weekend": "powderblue", "md": "black", "gu": "orange"}
for idx, val in cm18.iterrows():
    if val["weekend"]:
        ax18.plot(
            idx, val["value"], color=colors["weekend"]
        )
    else:
        ax18.plot(idx, val["value"], color=colors["gu"])
```

I have also tried seaborn lineplot with the hue parameter but it only treats with values that are weekends or that aren't like different time series and plots them along the same axis.
How can I achieve it taking into account that I want to be able to replicate it with festivities, which have more values than 0 or 1 as the can be national, regional or local? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a mockup figure that you have in your mind (handwritten is fine) :)